# Thread pooling in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, threadpool

I have 5 thread in a thread pool. If I got 10 request from a user how will I process 2 request per thread using cpp. I want to process request dynamically. My thread will remain same but request can be dynamic and I also want to display the log of thread execution

Comment: When some threads join back to the main thread, you can launch them again with on the new requests. You would only need to have a request vector and pull from it as time goes on and threads become free.

Answer (score 4):

The idea behind a thread pool is that there are a fixed number of threads, and when a new job request comes in, it will be assigned to an available thread.  If there is no available thread (i.e. all of the threads are already busy handling other jobs), then the job-request is added to the end of a FIFO queue.  Whenever a thread finishes with a job-request that it is currently handling, it checks the FIFO queue to see if job-requests are queued up there waiting to be handled.  If there is a job-request in the FIFO, the thread will pop it off of the head of the FIFO and handle it; if not, the thread will go to sleep until the next job-request comes along (at which point it, or another thread, will be woken up by the thread-pool so that the new job-request can be handled).

In this way an arbitrary number of job-requests can be handled using a finite number of threads.

Comment: The asker must be cognizant of the quality of the answer +1.                                                                                                       _If I had had an opportunity to study these topics from scratch, I'd have taken an eager interest in reading such a text._